# При помощи jQuery написать код, который будет делать кнопку активной, если чекбокс отмечен галочкой, и блокировать ее, если галочка отсутствует

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

как реализовать на jQuery?

код :

```
 HTML 
    
     <button class="send_button" id="sendNewSms"    >Отправить</button> 

 <div class="personal_checkbox        ">  
                Вы соглашаетесь на обработку персональных данных и ознакомлены с политикой конфиденциальности?
                
                 <input   id="checkme"   type="checkbox"  >
            </div>  
CSS 

 <div class="personal_checkbox        ">  
Вы соглашаетесь на обработку персональных данных и ознакомлены с политикой конфиденциальности?
         <input   id="checkme"   type="checkbox"  >
  </div>
```

JavaScript

```
var checker = document.getElementById('checkme')
  var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms')
  
  checker.onclick = function() {
    sendbtn.disabled = !this.checked
  }
  
  sendbtn.disabled = !this.checked
```

Comment: Можно спросить зачем? Или это учебное задание какое-то?

Comment: Да,учебное задание.

Comment: на js реализовал,не могу вникнуть в синтаксис jq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input').change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('#sendNewSms').prop('disabled',false)
  else $('#sendNewSms').prop('disabled',true)
})
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <button class="send_button" id="sendNewSms" disabled>Отправить</button> 
   <div class="personal_checkbox">  
      Вы соглашаетесь на обработку персональных данных и ознакомлены с политикой конфиденциальности?
      <input   id="checkme"   type="checkbox"  >
   </div> 
   <div class="personal_checkbox">  
      Вы соглашаетесь на обработку персональных данных и ознакомлены с политикой конфиденциальности?
      <input   id="checkme"   type="checkbox"  >
  </div>
```

Comment: зачем if else?)) `$('#sendNewSms').prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'))`

Comment: крутотень, поклон

Comment: Только при 1 запуске кнопка доступна,а после перекликивания начинает работать,а так да,спасибо!

Comment: @Dreams да, неверно прочитал. Поменял. Еще у вас у инупутов одинаковые id. Обратите внимание.

Comment: Bear Vorkuta  да,спасибо,это я случайно 2 раза один и тот же отрывок кода повторил

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]